# Toad throwing an error ora-00907 missing right parenthesis while in SQL Server query runs fine

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this create table query

```
create table person
(
    PersonId int primary key Identity(1,1),
    PersonName nvarchar(30),
    Email nvarchar(30),
    Age int
);
```

When I tried this query on Toad, this throws an error ora-00907 missing right parenthesis. But When I copy pasted the same on SQL Server Management Studio 2012, it ran perfectly fine there?

Comment: Because `ORACLE` <> `SQL SERVER`. Clearly its Sql Server syntax how do you expect it to run on Oracle. Oracle does not support `Identity`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Identity is not supported by Oracle.  In Oracle the code is a little bit more tricky.

You will have to create an auto-increment field with the sequence object (this object generates a number sequence).

```
CREATE SEQUENCE seq_person
MINVALUE 1
START WITH 1
INCREMENT BY 1
CACHE 10
```

The code above creates a sequence object called seq_person, that starts with 1 and will increment by 1. It will also cache up to 10 values for performance. The cache option specifies how many sequence values will be stored in memory for faster access.

To insert a new record into the "Persons" table, we will have to use the nextval function (this function retrieves the next value from seq_person sequence):

```
INSERT INTO Persons (ID,FirstName,LastName)
VALUES (seq_person.nextval,'Lars','Monsen')
```

Comment: Oracle 12 *does* support identity (but with a different syntax than SQL Server)

Answer (score 1):

As an adjunct to @Dhirendra's answer, you can use a BEFORE INSERT trigger to ensure that the ID field is filled in properly:

```
CREATE TRIGGER PERSON_BI
  BEFORE INSERT ON PERSON
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF :NEW.PERSONID IS NULL THEN
    :NEW.PERSONID := SEQ_PERSON.NEXTVAL;
  END IF;
END PERSON_BI;
```

Best of luck.